# BluetoothGatt returns empty service list after connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am building an app to read data from a ble device. After connecting to a device I call `mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices()` and in `onServicesDiscovered(..)` I am reading the list of service by calling `getServices()`.

The problem is sometimes the list is empty.Has anyone faced this issue.The issue is random and not 100% reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,this is a Common problem.If you get empty services,you can retry discover .
If you get empty more than 3 or 5 times,you should restart you Bluetooth,because it is may be unstable

Comment: What's the best way to "retry discover"?

Answer (score 0):

I just run into this, but even retrying the discovery, gatt services were empty. For me the solution was to restart both BLE and Android devices.